# How to update styled-components' variables depending on the media queries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

My theme is the following:

```
const theme = {color: red};
```

And I'm using this variable in components in this way:

```js
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.theme.color};
`;
```

And I want that if the screen width is less than 992, the color becomes green. How can I achieve this using styled components theming? Because, using css variables I can just do next:

```css
:root {
  --color: red;
  
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    --color: green;
  }
}
```

But in styled-components it's impossible. Just one way that I currently see is to set theme variables like this:

```
const theme = {color: var(--color)}
```

But in this situation I can't use this variable value in js. So, what can be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries with styled components in much the same way, so you if you had the two colours you wanted to use in your theme object, you would end up with something like

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${props => props.theme.colorRed};
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    color: ${props => props.theme.colorGreen};
  }
`;
```

Comment: But what if I wanna use this logic with color in multiple situations? 
WIll I need in each case copy-paste this code? Is there any more comfortable way?